# Question on Object Relation Mapper(ORM) doining the work of Relational Database(join)

Tags: mysql, sql, orm

Am new to ORM and all examples have seen so far have been on how I can use ORM to query just 2 tables only. My question now is How can I use ORM to query 3 tables and above. In Relational Database, you do this in querying 3 tables together.

```
SELECT user.id,name,email.id,mail.user_id,email,sport,sport.user_id FROM user LEFT JOIN mail ON email.user_id = user.id LEFT JOIN sport.user_id = user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

ORM doesn't restrict you to write native query. Some sophisticated ORM also comes with their version of "SQL". But under the hood, ORM need translate everything to native SQL. ORM is just a mapping from database to your object.

But since you are new to ORM, i would like to share this quote from the creator of hibernate

> Just because you're using Hibernate, doesn't mean you have to use it for everything. A point I've been making for about ten years now.

I would like to share another quote from the creator of JOOQ

> Don't use ORMs for querying 
>   Don't use SQL for complex CRUD